# Setting up a MySQL database between a few computers

Tags: mysql, networking

I'm a bit new to this field; I want to set up a MySQL database that can be accessed and updated by a few separate computers.

What are my options for this, and what would their advantages/dis-advantages be?

For example, I can create a MySQL server on one pc, and give remote access to other users (I believe); How secure is this, can users access the database despite the original pc being shut down etc.?

What about using Azure, services like it?

What type of solution would you recommend if I wanted to have my database accessible at all times, and updated hourly/daily automatically?

Answer (score 3):

No users can not access the database despite the original pc being shut down.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a common use case to have a MySQL server running on a computer in a network. You can connect to it from any computer in the same network, e.g. using MySQL workbench or any other MySQL client application or library. It is hosted as a regular TCP server using port 3306 by default.

Note that there is a way to constrict access to the database to `localhost` for certain users, which means that those users may only connect to the database from the computer hosting the server. This is used for the root user by default due to security considerations.

If the computer running the MySQL server is shut down, it will no longer be accessible, i.e. no means for decentralization are supported natively.

Comment: What type of solution would you recommend if I wanted to have my database accessible at all times, and updated hourly/daily automatically?

Comment: I'm coming from an environment, where we have a constantly running server available. If you don't have that, looking into cloud-based solutions certainly makes sense. I can't provide concrete recommendations though.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have  any server. You can use local tunnels to make your personal computer to a local server . People can access to your localhost , after installing wamp server to run php and mysql , install a local tunnel app on your system .
In below you can see some of them:

1. [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com)
2. [Pagekite](https://pagekite.net)
3. [forwardhq](https://forwardhq.com)

And in [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/) , you can find more. Also for access to mysql ,make a web service by php and use JSON data to send request beetwen client and server([like this](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php)).